# multiple Eval statements in one control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

Is it possible to have several <%# Eval("something")%> statements in one control, and if so, what am i doing wrong?

i'm trying to add hyperlinks to a datalist, where the navigateurl and text are retrived from a datatable i use use as datasource.

this is how i make my datatable

```
foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry ev in calFeed.Entries)
        {
            ExtensionCollection<When> v = ev.Times;
            DataRow Title = dt.NewRow();
            DataRow url = dt.NewRow();

            Title["title"] = ev.Title.Text;
            url["url"] = ev.Content.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(Title);
            dt.Rows.Add(url);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

this is my html

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("url")%>' runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("title")%> />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

now if i eval title in both fields they are shown, but if i chose two different like title and url, only one is evaluated, and the other is left blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating two rows, in your code.  Create just one row in your code and then add it:

```
foreach (Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry ev in calFeed.Entries)
        {
            ExtensionCollection<When> v = ev.Times;
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            dr["title"] = ev.Title.Text;
            dr["url"] = ev.Content.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
```

Comment: wow, it feels dumb to overlook that. i'll mark your answer as correct when i can (in 5 mins)